# Write directly to a hadoop map file from reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a reduce method as in which a file is selected based on a timestamp in the record.

The timestamp in the data can belong to N different days.(say N=5)
Based on the day,a file is selected and a MapFile Writer is selected with respective path.
There are N writers for N paths

```
 Example : to write record 15-02-2016,Key1,value1 
 A Map File writer object writing to basePath/15-02-2016  will be selected 
and writes key1,value1 using selected writer.
```

Below is the reduce method

```
 @Override
 protected void reduce(CompositeKey key,Iterable<SomeDataWritable> dataList,
          Reducer<CompositeKey, SomeDataWritable, Text, OutputWritable>.Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          for(SomeDataWritable data:dataList){
            MyMapFileWriter.write(key.getTimeStamp(),key.getId(),new OutPutWritable(data);
           }
}

MyMapFileWriter.write(long timestamp,Text key,OutPutWritable value){
writer=selectWriter(timestamp)// select writer based on timestamp
writer.append(key,value)
}
```

Key is sorted on (Day,id) . Partitioner is based on Day and GroupingComparator is based on (Day,id)
**So a call to reduce should get all records of a single day sorted by Id.
Is it ok here to write to a file directly from reduce?**

Keys written to map file should be in ascending order ,can multiple parallel invocations of the reduce method(on same reducer node) cause out of order keys?

Also even without any context.write in reduce the job output path has some output(I ran in local mode in eclipse).This could be mapper output being written by Hadoop Reducer's reduce().How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that writing to some files directly through writers isn't good idea, because it is at odds with hadoop idea related to fault tolerance: you run your job, something fails at one node, hadoop tries to reschedule job, but due to the fact that you write to files without hadoop standard mechanism it can't do anything with failed partial results (you should handle it by yourself).

According to "out of order keys". I am not sure that I understood your question, but one reducer will process data for one key , e.g. one reducer can process data for key <2016-02-02, id1>, another reducer can process records for key <2016-02-01, id2> etc.

If you understood you correctly, you should specify reduce output path `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, OUTPUT_PATH)` in your configuration so input and output paths will be different. In this case you will receive files in OUTPUT_PATH which will be related to reducers.

Comment: If there are 3 containers on a reducer node and the reducers gets all keys for 2016-02-02 ,say <2016-02-02, id1>  and <2016-02-02, id2> .Can it happen that two processes on the node are trying to write to the same file selected by the same day value from the key?
I have to write records in reducer based on directories of day and setOutputPath can't do that.I can use mutipleOutputs ,where each reducer will be writing their path(based on day key they receive).One reducer will be writing to one path only.

Comment: Yes, it can happen. Records for one key. e.g. <2016-02-02, id1> will be processed in one reducer. But keys <2016-02-02, id1>, <2016-02-02, id2> are different, so they can be processed by two different reducer processes.

Comment: And it looks like it is better to use mutipleOutputs mechanism (not using direct writes to hdfs) because in this case fault talerance will be correct.